# Deriving the New Keynesian Phillips Curve (NKPC)

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, new-keynesian-economics, dsge

I have a question regarding the NKPC. I would like to know if it is possible to derive the NKPC from a sticky prices model, without making assumptions regarding the production function firms face. I am trying to estimate an open economy NKPC. As far as I am concerned, much of the extensions of the NKPC for the open economy involve substituting the commonly used Cobb-Douglas function for  another one which explicitly incorporates imported goods. Some examples of this approach are  [Galí and López-Salido](https://www.bde.es/f/webbde/SES/Secciones/Publicaciones/PublicacionesSeriadas/DocumentosTrabajo/01/Fic/dt0109e.pdf), [Balakrishnan and López-Salido](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/working-paper/2002/understanding-uk-inflation-the-role-of-openness),  and [Rumler](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11079-007-9028-6). However, almost all of the the derivations of the NKPC assume that firms face a Cobb-Douglass production function, as you can see in [Gali and Gertler](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304393299000239), [Galí and López-Salido](https://www.bde.es/f/webbde/SES/Secciones/Publicaciones/PublicacionesSeriadas/DocumentosTrabajo/01/Fic/dt0109e.pdf), [Balakrishnan and López-Salido](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/working-paper/2002/understanding-uk-inflation-the-role-of-openness), [Romer](https://b-ok.lat/book/5329009/5a8c0b), and [Galí](https://b-ok.lat/book/873271/6033fc). Wouldn´t there be a contradicction if (this is the approach followed by [Balakrishnan and López-Salido](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/working-paper/2002/understanding-uk-inflation-the-role-of-openness)), one assumes that firms face a Cobb-Douglas function but at the aggregate level one assumes a different production function, such as a CES production function that incorporates imported inputs? I am having trouble with reconciling the assumption of different production functions. Because of this apparent contradiction, I thought that, if it is posibble to derive the NKPC from a sticky prices model without assuming a Cobb-Douglass production function (or any other production function for that matter), I could easily bypass the problem.  Hope I made my case clear. Thank you in advance!

P.S. I know that [Rumler](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11079-007-9028-6) derives a NKPC assuming just a CES  production function. However, I havent been able to understand exactly how he estimated the coefficients of his model nor what variables he actually used. For an undergradute such as me, estimating such a model seems to be out of reach. However, if someone is willing to give me a hand, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Econ Stack Exchange. Try not to use abbreviations unless you first define them. This helps with discoverability with search engines, not to mention the average reader.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I didn't notice I hadn't. I have fixed it. Thanks!